# Floating Action Bar (not button) in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I am working on `Floating Action Bar` on top of keyboard if user clicks on one of the `EditText`. I couldn't start on it and that's why not have any code to present.

I am confused on how to approach this problem. I am considering to use `bottom sheet` but I am still not getting confidence on it (I think android should have something better to use as base for this `view`).

I don't need any code snippet but need a direction. I am new to `Android` and before jumping to implementation, I needed a direction to start with.

Any suggestions? I am implementing
something similar to `Outlook` app.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a bottom sheet. I'd use a view that's hidden when the soft keyboard is not visible, and show it once the soft keyboard is up.  You don't mention if this is to be build with XML views or compose views to help you more, but there are many examples of how to pin a view over the softkeyboard.  Don't forget also the windowSoftInputMode flags

Answer (score 1):

So this floating toolbar is just a view that contains icons to press. This view should be located as the bottommost view on the screen. If you're using a `ConstraintLayout` use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.

And the `android:windowSoftInputMode` for hosting activity can be set to `adjustResize` ([doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)).

So when the keyboard opens it pushes this bottommost view up (and now this view is right above the keyboard).